# Why is $http indicating an error when the backend indicates success?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a very simple API call that deletes a resource.  On the front end:

```
  o.destroy = function (unit_id, alarm, index) {
  return $http.delete('/api/alarms', alarm).then(function (data) {
    console.log('success');
  }, function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

And on the backend

```
exports.destroy_alarm =  function(req, res, next) {
 TimeSeriesAlarm.findOneAndRemove({id: req.body._id},
   function(err, result){
    res.status(201).json([]);
  });
};
```

The server logs a successful API request, and the resource gets deleted.  However, I have to make the call between 5-10 times before I get back a successful request on the front end.  Usually I get this:

```
Object
config
:
Object
data:null
headers:(d)
status:-1
statusText
:
""
```

Angular documentation says "-1 usually means the request was aborted, e.g. using a config.timeout"  However that's not the case.  The resource is delete successfully every time, it's just the status that's wrong.

Comment: Just because the resource is deleted doesn't necessarily mean the response is returned before the timeout. The `TimeSeriesAlarm.findOneAndRemove` function could take more time than the timeout in the config

Comment: I think the issue might be that I am passing a timeout property in the body of the request, since the TimeSeriesAlarm actually has its own timeout property, but the request is interpreting that for its own use instead

Comment: The second argument to `$http.delete` is the optional config object. Show us the code for that. There are a lot of things that can cause a status -1 (AngularJS internal error). Without seeing the code, we can only guess at what is wrong.